# how to use standard output from multiple commands as file arguments

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, redirection

I want to compare the output of 2 commands.

For example:

```
$ command1 arguments1 > tempfile1
$ command2 arguments2 > tempfile2
$ diff tempfile1 tempfile2 > savefile
$ rm tempfile1 tempfile2
```

Is there a clever way to do this? Hopefully in one line, and without the need for temporary files.

So, it would be something like (but obviously not exactly this):

```
$ diff $(command1 arguments1) $(command2 arguments2) > savefile
```

My machine info is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux host.name 3.2.54 #9 SMP Thu Feb 13 08:17:11 CST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ which sh
/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, you can use process substitution:

```
diff <(command1 arguments1) <(command2 arguments2) > savefile
```

Note that this will not work in plain sh (or even bash in "posix mode", i.e. when invoked under the name "sh" and it turns off some features for compatibility). It is available in zsh, though.

Comment: What do you mean **`bash in plain-sh emulation mode`**?

Comment: @KevinFegan: On some systems, /bin/sh is actually bash (either a link or a copy of /bin/bash); if run with this name, bash enters "posix mode" (what I called plain-sh emulation mode), and turns off a number of its advanced (and nonstandard) features. This mode can also be invoked by running bash with the `--posix` option, or with the command `set -o posix`. I'll edit my answer to clarify...